# Xcode 5 : Different screen sized iPhones Autolayout views resizing issue

Tags: ios5, xcode5, autolayout

Using Xcode 5, Storyboard and trying to make an application to work in both 3.5 inch and 4 inch screen iPhones.
I am new to AutoLayout. Trying to figure out the below.
Got [image: View control screenshot]

Trying to set autolayout such that the three black background views are not resized when different screen sized iPhones are used.

Added the following constraints:

A) Release 1 (blackscreen):
1. Top Space to Superview
2. Leading Space to Superview

B) Release 2 (blackscreen):
1. Leading Space to Superview
2. Trailing Space to Superview

C) Release 3 (Blackscreen):
1.Leading Space to Superview
2. Trailing Space to Superview
3. Bottom Space to Superview

A & B are set to have same height

Above all set for 4 inch screen But when 3.5 inch screen size is selected as simulator,

A & B are getting collapsed on each other. How to have the Equi-distance between all the three views ?

Can extra Empty views in between the views to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Little relief by following the below:

1. Add vertical spacing between A & B
2. Add vertical spacing between B & C with priority 380
3. Still not exact spacing is achieved but this looks like a heads-up for the solution.

Would update the post once its completely solved. Still more labels, are to be added into each A, B & C to show the views as planned.

[image]